# Errors and Warnings in clues

Tags: cryptic-clues, puzzle-creation, anagram

I want to use "Error" and "Warning" as anagram indicators, like this:

> Run Time Error (4) --- **EMIT**
>   Error: Please get a rest (6) --- **ASLEEP** (not sure yet)
>   Error 106E: Something Wrong (4) --- **VICE** (not sure yet)

But I'm not sure.

**Is it allowed to use "error" and "warning" in my clues?**

EDIT: You can give another example using "error" or "warning".

Comment: how did you use 'warning'?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry , maybe as a homophone indicator.

Comment: I'm a bit appalled that this question should exist at all. I am strongly of the opinion that you should be able to do as you god damn well please, and as long as the result is a good puzzle, to heck with anyone claiming that your artistic creation was too original and didn't conform with §12 of the art union's acceptable art creation process document 12.4, section b-45. (Please ignore my rant, by the the way, I just happen to live in a country where this particular art embraces and encourages all kinds of creativity, the more novel and clever the cryptic clue, the better.)

Answer (score 5):

I think "error" *can* be an anagram indicator, but there are some caveats.

> Run Time Error (4)

I would be fine with this. "Error" is applicable to the previous word in the same way that "news organization" might give SEWN; it's an error of the word "time", so a "time error". (The strictest of Ximenians typically don't allow nouns as anagram indicators at all. I'm fairly strict, but even I'm fine with this.)

> Error: Please get a rest (6)

This one doesn't work as well. I can't think of any analogous situations that I would accept -- I don't think "error: X" means "anagram of X". (Also, "get a rest" is not a synonym for ASLEEP; "*getting* rest" is.)

> Error 106E: Something Wrong (4)

And your third has the same major problem as the second. Anagram indicators that are nouns typically can't go before the text they change; there's not really a feasible way for 'error' to modify the word coming after it with the correct meaning.

For example, "error message" means "message *about* an error [in some other program]", not "message that itself has an error". I don't think there's a way to finish the phrase "error ___" to mean "___ that has(/is) an error" - and *that* would be the required reading to get "error" to work as an anagram indicator.

---

In addition, your third clue is an indirect anagram, which many publishers and setters do not accept. A clue like

> Grotesque monster is tough (5)

giving the answer HARDY (anagram of "hydra") is generally not fair, because there are way too many possible monsters. This type of construction -- where you take a synonym (or do some other wordplay) and *then* anagram -- is called an "indirect anagram". It's generally considered a Very Bad Thing™, because it's unfair to the solver. It's not *as* bad in this case as it could be, but "avoid indirect anagrams" is a good general rule.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia doesn't list 'error' or 'warning' as [anagram indicators for cryptic clues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptic_crossword#Anagrams), but I personally can't see a problem - they both have 'disruption' as a synonym, which 'arguably' should be on the list as well.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Deusovi.  A lot of this is opinion, but I think 'error' is fine but 'warning' doesn't feel right. Error means something is wrong with the indicated word, but Warning doesn't indicate something broken or altered.

In a puzzle I'm currently creating, I have the the clue

> User error scam (4)

so I've thought along the same lines...

Comment: looking forward to your high-quality puzzles :)

Comment: Answer is ruse.